# where clause with multiple condition on same table

Tags: mysql

I have searched for this topic and found many threads, but I'm sorry I was not able find solution/idea.

I have a table as below

Name  | Technology 
Res1  | Java 
Res1  | MySQL 
Res2  | Java 
Res3  | Java 
Res3  | PHP 
Res3  | MySQL 
Res4  | MySQL 
Res4  | PHP 
and so on..

I want to build a relation table as

Name  | similarResource 
Res1  | Res3
Res2  | Res1, Res3
Res3  | null
Res4  | Res3

It is to understand similar resources available in pool. I tried to create stored procedure with cursor, but not able to proceed. 
steps I am trying to build,
1. For each resource in table, find list of technology they are familiar with 
2. using the result, search through the table to find the resources who are all having same tech. 
I tried using IN and results in expensive query.

please suggest a better way.

Comment: you just need a self join and `group_concat()`.

Comment: My best guess at how you can approach this using a somewhat efficient approach, is to assign each tech a bitwise value (i.e. `1` for java, `10`, for MySQL, etc.) and use bitwise operators do do the work.  Outside of that, you are looking at some heinous group_concat, substring action to define your join conditions.

Comment: @MarcB I think it's more complicated than that. A similar Resource must have *all* the technologies to match not just *any*

Comment: Why is res4 similar to res3? Res3 has java, but res4 does not. Put simply, to be similar is it that the similar resource must have every tech that the first column has and may have others too? ie a superset?

Comment: Bohemian, thanks for pointing it out. i have modified my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to meet the requirement that a similar res must have all of the matching technology you'll can compare counts of the matching technology using inline views

```
SELECT counts.name, 
       Group_concat(matchCount.name) simliarName 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               Count(technology) techCount 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY name) counts 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.name              t1_name, 
                         t2.name, 
                         Count(t2.technology) matchingTech 
                  FROM   table1 t1 
                         JOIN table1 t2 
                           ON t1.technology = t2.technology 
                              AND t1.name != t2.name 
                  GROUP  BY t1.name, 
                            t2.name) matchCount 
              ON counts.name = matchcount.t1_name 
                 AND counts.techcount <= matchCount.matchingtech 
GROUP  BY counts.name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/014165/30)

Comment: you deserve +200 for this :). you got +1 from me :)

Comment: Conard, Thanks for saving my day. logic worked perfectly. I'll modify them to my needs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself and use the group_concat function to create the list:

```
select x.name, group_concat(distinct y.name2) as similarResource
from (select name, count(*) c from mytable group by 1) x
join (select t.name, s.name name2, count(*) c
  from mytable t
  join mytable s on t.technology = s.technology
  and t.name != s.name
  group by 1, 2) y on x.name = y.name
where y.c >= x.c
group by 1
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64229/12), with the following output using your sample data:

```
NAME    SIMILARRESOURCE
Res1    Res3
Res2    Res1,Res3
Res4    Res3
```

Note that the output of this query does not include `Res3 | Res4`, because Res4 does not have "java" (either your sample data is missing some rows, or I have misunderstood the question).

Comment: This isn't correct. This matches on "any" technology rather than "all" . For example your result for the first row would be "Res3,Res4,Res2,Res3" when the OP wants only Res3.

Comment: @ConradFrix thx - I misunderstood the question (and it took a while to figure out what I think is a good solution... which I have just realised is basically the same as yours :/)

Comment: Thanks Bohemian for your support.